# Read float numbers from a file and add them in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file temp.txt. Float values are present in that.

```
cat temp.txt

43.51
26.52
63.31
21.36
1.01
13.91
19.64
30.98
```

I want add these values.

Please someone help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{s+=$0}END{print s}' tmp.txt

kent$  echo "43.51
26.52
63.31
21.36
1.01
13.91
19.64
30.98"|awk '{s+=$0}END{print s}'
220.24
```

Comment: Found the answer in a generalize way :)

#!/bin/bash 

file="/basepath/temp.txt" 

sum=`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=$i}END{print s}' $file`

echo $sum

Comment: @sasuke the awk line in your comment won't work for your temp.txt. you have one number in each line. the awk line you found works all numbers in one line, separated by space

Answer (score 1):

try this short variant

```
paste -sd+ temp.txt|bc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 'bc' based version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tally=0
while read value
do
    tally=`echo "scale=3;${value} + ${tally}" | bc`         
done < tmp.txt
```

Where tmp.txt contains:

```
43.51
26.52
63.31
21.36
1.01
13.91
19.64
30.98
```

And running output is:

```
 ./script-math 
220.24
```

Can be modified to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tally=0
while read value
do
    tally=`echo "scale=3;${value} + ${tally}" | bc`         
done
```

So that you can:

```
cat tmp.txt | ./script-math
```